# Defining variables in Azure Cosmos DB Graph query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am struggling with running the pagination script on Azure Cosmos DB Graph, using Gremlin.NET:

```
t = g.V().hasLabel('person');[]
t.next(2)
t.next(2)
```

It comes from [Tinkerpop page](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/docs/src/recipes/pagination.asciidoc) where it is described how to reuse traversal instance to avoid loading the whole graph.

Unfortunately, in Gremlin .NET I get:

```
ExceptionType : GraphSyntaxException
ExceptionMessage :
  Gremlin query syntax error: Unsupported groovy expression kind: t=g.V().hasLabel('person') @ line 1, column 1.
```

Probably this kinda structure is not supported by Azure Cosmos DB Graph, but I cannot find any materials that would prove it.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this too. Do you have any update @Radoslaw ?